# Android setTextOn not working in onCheckChanged method

Tags: java, android, settext

These next two statements produce *correct* screen below left:

```
                if(isChecked) sw.setText   ("This switch is: On"); 
                else          sw.setText   ("This switch is: Off");
```

According to the text I'm looking at, these next two statements *should* produce screen on left. But they produce **incorrect** screen below right:

```
                if(isChecked) sw.setTextOn ("This switch is: On"); 
                else          sw.setTextOff("This switch is: Off");
```

[image]   [image]

The code:

```
package com.dslomer64.checkbox;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{//} implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    CheckBox cb;
    Switch sw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                    cb.setText("checked");
                else
                    cb.setText("Unchecked");
            }
        });

        sw = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.swish);
        sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                    sw.setTextOn("This switch is: On"); ////////////
                else
                    sw.setTextOff("This switch is: Off"); //////////

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" android:weightSum="1">

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="453dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/swish"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:text="Unchecked"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is the book wrong about `setTextOn` and `setTextOff`? Do I have a problem in java code or xml?

Comment: I don't think your calls to `setTextOn` and `setTextOff` need to be in an `if` - they just define how the toggle appears when on or off, so they don't need to be set conditionally. Ref: [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html#setTextOff%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setTextOn` and `setTextOff` functions are to used to set the labels depending on the state of the `Switch`.

The text "The switch is: On" is just the label of your Switch and does not
convey the state of your `Switch`.

To achieve the result that you want, you need to call `setShowText(true)`:

```
sw = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.swish);
sw.setShowText(true);
```

or you can add it in your XML.

```
<Switch
        android:layout_width="453dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/swish"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"     
        android:showText="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As observed by @Simon M, this xml and java snippet produce consistent output as shown by the screen below.

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="453dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/swish"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textOn="ON!!"
    android:textOff="OFF!"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>



    sw = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.swish);
    sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          // absolutely nothing
        });
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The following xml and java produce what the text was aiming for:

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="453dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/swish"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="This switch is...OFF"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>



    sw = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.swish);
    sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
                sw.setText("Switch is ON!");
            else
                sw.setText("Switch is OFF!");
        }
    });
```

... which is this:

[image]